# Codeacademy question Sum of Pairs(pyhton)

Tags: python, arrays, list

Question:
Given a list of integers and a single sum value, return the first two values (parse from the left please) in order of appearance that add up to form the sum.

If there are two or more pairs with the required sum, the pair whose second element has the smallest index is the solution.
My solution:

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    lst = []
    for i in range(len(ints)):
        for j in range(len(ints)):
            if ints[i] + ints[j] == s and  i != j:
                lst.append([ints[i], ints[j], max(i, j)])
    temp = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[2])
    print(len(temp))
    if len(temp) == 0:
        return lst
    else:
        return [temp[0][0], temp[0][1]]
```

In this code [20, -13, 40] and sum = -7 it is expected to return None but my code is returning [20, -13, 40]. Even though I didn't append any of the values. How could this happen?

Comment: When I run your code on the input you mentioned, I'm seeing an empty list.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is returning empty list..